# How to call OnChange Event of DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

1. I have a button and when I click on the button I want to reload my DatePicker accordingly and launch the beforeShowDay event of the datePicker  from my click event.
   How can I do that?
2. How to set the DatePicker date  to the ListDate[0] date?

   ```
   var ListDate = new Array();
   var ID;
       $(function ()
       {
                 $("#myDateDiv").datepicker({
           showOtherMonths: true,
           selectOtherMonths: true,
           dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
           onSelect: function (dateText, inst)
           {                     
              //             
           },
           onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) 
           { 

       },
           beforeShowDay: function(dateToShow)
           {
               testFunction(dateToShow, ID);
               ListDate = getListdateFuction();
               ///How to set the datePicker date to ListDate[0] 
           });  
                  });
       });
   ```

   ---

   ```
   $("test").click(function(){
   How to call datePicker berforeShowDay or onChange function ???
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set the date use setDate

```
$("test").click(function(){
   $('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2011,5,12) );
});
```

the onChangeMonthYear will be triggered when you you change the month see [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/buMzS/)

Comment: setting the date is simple, but I would rather launchthe ONChnage function as well.  How do I set the date in the above piece of code?